# count of checked check bob by data attribute

Tags: jquery, html

i have a checkboxes like this 
i need to get how many checkbox is checked by using class "levelTwo" and data-parent-id = 2

In here the expected result is 3
because three checkbox is checked with data-parent-id=2 and the class ="levelTwo"

```
<input type="checkbox" class="userPerm levelTwo" data-permid="10" data-userid="25" data-parent-id="2" checked>

<input type="checkbox" class="userPerm levelTwo" data-permid="10" data-userid="25" data-parent-id="2">

<input type="checkbox" class="userPerm levelTwo" data-permid="10" data-userid="25" data-parent-id="2" checked>

<input type="checkbox" class="userPerm levelTwo" data-permid="10" data-userid="25" data-parent-id="2" checked>

<input type="checkbox" class="userPerm levelTwo" data-permid="10" data-userid="25" data-parent-id="3">

<input type="checkbox" class="userPerm levelTwo" data-permid="10" data-userid="25" data-parent-id="4">


<input type="checkbox" class="userPerm levelTwo" data-permid="10" data-userid="25" data-parent-id="4">
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Use [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

   > Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

```js
console.log($(":checkbox.levelTwo:checked[data-parent-id=2]").length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="userPerm levelTwo" data-permid="10" data-userid="25" data-parent-id="2" checked>

<input type="checkbox" class="userPerm levelTwo" data-permid="10" data-userid="25" data-parent-id="2">

<input type="checkbox" class="userPerm levelTwo" data-permid="10" data-userid="25" data-parent-id="2" checked>

<input type="checkbox" class="userPerm levelTwo" data-permid="10" data-userid="25" data-parent-id="2" checked>

<input type="checkbox" class="userPerm levelTwo" data-permid="10" data-userid="25" data-parent-id="3">

<input type="checkbox" class="userPerm levelTwo" data-permid="10" data-userid="25" data-parent-id="4">


<input type="checkbox" class="userPerm levelTwo" data-permid="10" data-userid="25" data-parent-id="4">
```

Comment: @Muhammadali glad to help mate